# Попытка написания дерева, в котором в качестве указателей на потомков используется динамический массив

Tags: c++

Вершина дерева содержит  указатель на строку и динамический массив указателей на потомков. Размерность динамического массива в корневой вершине - N, на каждом следующем уровне - в 2 раза больше.
Столкнулся с проблемой бесконечного выполнения рекурсии. Для ограничения создал переменную s, но не помогло.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
int lv=1;//уровень дерева
int maxl,N,N1,d,pp;
int dc = 0;
int s = 0;
using namespace std;
struct  tree
{        
    char *yk;            // указатель на строку
    tree* child;    //массив указателей на потомков
};

void viewTree(tree* begin, int sizeTree) {
    int power1 = 0, power2 = 1;
    int N = 1;
    tree* childTree = begin;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeTree; i++) {
        int u = 0;
        cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < pow(2, power1); j++) {
            if (u == N) {
                u = 0;
                cout << "} {";
            }
            if (childTree->yk == NULL) {
                cout << "O";
            }
            else {
                cout << childTree->yk;
            }
            if (j != pow(2, power1) - 1 and u != N - 1) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            childTree++;
            u++;
        }
        cout << "}";
        childTree = childTree->child;
        cout << endl;
        power1 = power1 + power2;
        power2++;
        N = 2 * N;
    }
}
string rec(tree* ptr, int N) //функция построения дерева через рекурсию
{
    if (s != pp)
    {
        char c[10];
        tree* p = ptr;
        cout << "Enter the string: ";
        cin >> c;
        if (strcmp(c, "skip") == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                ptr->yk[i] = '/0';
        }
        else
            ptr->yk = c;
        tree* temp = new tree;
        tree* child = new tree[2 * N];
        ptr->child = child;
        if (lv == maxl)
        {
            dc++;
            if (dc == N1)
            {
                dc = 0;
                lv--;
                return(ptr->yk);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (lv != maxl)lv++;
            rec(&ptr->child[i], 2 * N);
        }
        s++;
    }
}
string rec1(tree* ptr, int N) //функция обхода дерева
{
    tree* p = ptr;
    cout <<p->yk;
    if (lv >= maxl)
    {
        lv = 1;
        return(ptr->yk);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        lv++;
        rec1(&p->child[i], 2 * N);
    }
}
tree* Create(char val[],int N)
{
    tree* child = new tree[N];
    tree* tr;
    char *ch;
    tr = (struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    tr->yk =val;
    tr->child= new tree[N];
    rec(&tr->child[1],N);
    viewTree(tr,maxl);
    return(tr);
}
void add(tree* ptr, int a)
{
    struct tree* temp;
    temp = ptr;
    for (;;)
    {

    }
}//функция добавления элемента 
int main()
{
    pp = 0;
    d=1;
   // cout << "Enter the desired child number: ";
   // cin >> N;
    N = 2;
    N1 = N;
    tree* p;
    char value[10]; //массив для хранения содержимого ячейки
    //cout << "Enter the number of tree levels: ";
   // cin >> maxl;
    maxl = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxl-1; i++)
    {
        d *= N1;
        pp += d;
        if(i!=maxl-2)
        N1 *= 2;
    }
    pp--;
    cout << "Enter the value of the root: ";
    cin >> value;
    p = Create(value,N); //создание корня дерева
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему вы выделяете память только под структуры, а не под их данные ? char *yk - указатель на строку => нужно выделить память под эту строку (new char[длина строки]) и копировать в область памяти данные (strcpy(ptr->yk, c)), а не присваивать указатель на временный массив (ptr->yk = c;)

Comment: @DSuhoi , Окей. не использовал функцию так как банально не знал о ней.

Comment: @DSuhoi попробовал использовать функцию strcopy_s, так как MVS ругается на обычную. выдало ошибку: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7A5CF71F (ucrtbased.dll) в лаба 6.2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCDCDCDCD.

Comment: Вот [пример](http://cpp.sh/4dh23) выделения памяти и копирования в неё данных. (Не слышал о strcopy_s. Может strcpy_s вы хотели использовать ?)

Comment: Да, именно ее. Исправил , но все равно рекурсия выполняется бесконечно

Comment: Вообще у вас односвязный линейный список, а не дерево. Вот [статья](https://prog-cpp.ru/data-ols/), которая поможет вам улучшить алгоритм.

Comment: Статью видел, и про олс, и про двусвязный циклический список. Но не могу понять почему у меня не дерево а олс....

Comment: Почитайте о [бинарных деревьях](https://prog-cpp.ru/data-tree/).

Comment: @DSuhoi, эту тоже читал. И если бы у меня было бинарное дерево, все было бы намного проще. Не могли бы вы указать , где конкретно мое дерево ведет себя как олс?

Comment: Значит вы не читали. "Дерево – структура данных, представляющая собой древовидную структуру в виде набора связанных узлов." У вас один узел (указатель на следующий элемент списка), а в дереве их два (левая и правая ветви) и элементы всегда упорядочены относительно первого элемента дерева.

Comment: в задании указано, что потомков может быть не 2, а N, и указатели на них хранятся в динамическом массиве.

Comment: А где у вас условия выхода из рекурсии ? У вас код не доходит до инкрементирования переменной 's', т.е. цикл for - вечный. (Я говорил о бинарном дереве)

Comment: @DSuhoi, не подскажете варианты решения проблемы? попробовал в случае невыполнения условия, то есть когда количество выполнений дойдет до критической отметки вернуть значение, но проблема осталась

Comment: Так у вас с памятью проблемы могут быть (каждый раз элемент 'N' растёт в два раза => и памяти столько выделяется). Попробуйте переписать программу без использования глобальных переменных или уменьшить их количество.

Comment: @DSuhoi, я кажется понял, спасибо. Удваивал N для перехода на следующий уровень но оно удваивалось каждый раз